# is the <head> tag a regular tag that is not displayed by default

Tags: html

I noticed when looking at a webpage in Chrome that the `<head>` tag had the CSS `{display: none;}` assigned.

This got me thinking, is the `<head>` tag just a regular tag that browsers decide not to display

Even though this would have no obvious use, could I instead use a `<cheese>` tag in the place of the `<head>` tag and use the css `"cheese {display: none;}"`, to achieve the same function as a `<head>` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of pure display - yes `{display:none;}` will hide your element.

However HTML `<head>` has a distinct meaning in HTML as a container for the head elements, whereas `<cheese>` does not share this.

Browsers know it's not to be displayed and search engine crawlers *understand* the special meaning of the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 7):

### `<head>` and `display:none`

Yes, the `<head>` tag is a regular tag just like any others with the default user agent stylesheet having `display:none;` applied to it. I cool trick you can do to prove this is to show your styles:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tznvp/)

```
head,
style {
    display:block;
}
```

For extra fun you can add `contenteditable` to your head tag so you can edit the page's styles from within the page.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tznvp/1/)

### `<cheese>`

As for creating some random tag like `<cheese>`, this does not work (well may not) as expected because the browser is not expecting it. When you do things in HTML that aren't in the specification it may not be handled in a standard way.

An example of this is when you attempt to use the new HTML5 semantic tags (`<section>`, `<nav>`, ...) in older versions of IE, they don't recognise them and garble the page up. Bringing in Modernizr applies some polyfills to fix this and emulate a regular `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

The browser renders the document *body* which is contained within the `<body></body>` tag pairs. This is the part of the document that is rendered and shown.

HTML defines its own set of tags and attributes that make up the language. The document type declaration (DTD) defines what set of tags and attributes the enclosed document is using. So when your DTD is for HTML5, you use HTML5-specific tags and attributes (or rather, you *should* and the browser should do the same).

So if you want to add your own tag to the mix, like say `<cheese>` you could put it anywhere in the document, if its in the `<body></body>` tag pairs, more likely the browser will render the tag literally (since it is not part of HTML and it doesn't know what to do with it).

If you were to add it before the `<body></body>` tags, then your document will not be *well formed* (that is, it is not following the rules of the HTML document type), however it will have no effect on what is rendered by the browser.

Comment: "HTML is a subset of XML" No.